# What's an efficient way to call a function with variable arguments?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm working on a Javascript module which accepts a function and at a later point allows you call it, not unlike currying. I noticed that NodeJS switched from always using `.apply()` to using a `switch` statement like the one below.

```
function applyFn(fn, args, ctx) {
    switch (args.length) {
        case 0: return fn.call(ctx); break;
        case 1: return fn.call(ctx, args[0]); break;
        case 2: return fn.call(ctx, args[0], args[1]); break;
        case 3: return fn.call(ctx, args[0], args[1], args[2]); break;
        default: return fn.apply(ctx, args);
    }
}
```

Is the above example any better than this version below?

```
function applyFn(fn, args, ctx) {
    if (4 in args) return fn.apply(ctx, args);
    if (3 in args) return fn.call(ctx, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
    if (2 in args) return fn.call(ctx, args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    if (1 in args) return fn.call(ctx, args[0], args[1]);
    if (0 in args) return fn.call(ctx, args[0]);
    return fn.call(ctx); // ಠ_ಠ
}
```

Which version has better performance?

**EDIT:** Here is how I'm using it: [named-parameters.js](https://gist.github.com/sirlancelot/e1d2ba6c8e07cbf61bd1)

Comment: Why not `call()` directly? What about those `if` and `switch` ?

Comment: This seems like a micro-optimization.

Comment: This is pretty strange.  You'd think V8 would be smart enough to do this itself.

Comment: The `in` operator is probably slower than a `switch` statement. However, use  http://jsperf.com to answer such questions. Or write your own benchmark. Anything else is just speculation.

Comment: This is intended to be a browser plugin so it might not always run in V8.

Comment: Wondering why they used a switch in the first place....

Comment: http://jsperf.com/applyfn Looks like the switch is much faster when the number of arguments is small.

Comment: If this is really a micro optimization, as it looks like, you'll probably degrade performance, as I've heard JavaScript `in` performance is not very good. I can even assure with 51% of certainty that just using `.apply`, no ifs and switchs, will be better than using `in`.

Comment: I made a JSPerf, thanks for your comments!

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Apparently it's not smart enough. Maybe we should open a bug on optimising `apply`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I think that would be a good idea.  Otherwise when `apply` really does get faster, the above example would have unnecessary overhead and verbosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is kind of a micro-optimization but since my module does one thing I want to make sure it does it well.

I crafted a test here: http://jsperf.com/switch-vs-case-function-call

`switch` definitely looks to be the winner for both 4 and 1 arg calls.